# IllegalArgumentException when using Int.MAX_VALUE as page size in Jetpack compose HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, illegalargumentexception, horizontal-pager

I have implemented a infinite scrolling HorizontalPager in Jetpack compose. Intially it worked ok but recently i am getting (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce value to an empty range: maximum -1564.0 is less than minimum 0.0) error when i scroll the pager. I dont actually know when did this happened.

Sample code

```
val listSize = exploreList.size
val pageCount = Int.MAX_VALUE
val maxRounds = pageCount / listSize
val initialPage = (maxRounds / 2) * listSize
val pagerState =
    rememberPagerState(initialPage = initialPage, pageCount = { pageCount })

HorizontalPager(
state = pagerState,
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 54.dp),
) {
    val page = it % exploreList.size
    val id = exploreList.getOrNull(page)?.id ?: 0
    val posterPath = exploreList.getOrNull(page)?.posterPath
    ExploreListItem(
        posterPath = posterPath,
        modifier =
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(4F / 5F)
            .carousalTransition(it, pagerState),
        onClick = { navigateToMovieDetails(id) },
    )
}
```

## Version details

Compose BOM version: `2023.10.01`

Kotlin version: `1.9.21`

For now I replaced Int.MAX_VALUE with a constant value like: `val pageCount = 1000`. Here no problem.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: val pageCount = Int.MAX_VALUE
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = pageCount / 2) {
        pageCount
    }

You can update with the above and still it will be a infinite pager. I don't understand why you wanna multiple it with list size again.

Comment: @pepperlove It's because when the pageCount / 2, the initialPage in the pager will not the first item in the list. To make the initialPage in the pager same as the first item in list the maxRounds and initialPage variable is used. But the actual problem is not that here!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this appears to have been a bug in the beta version of the compose foundation library. See the relevant issue here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/311414925

That being said, you still might run into this other issue with trying to do infinite paging in 1.6.x versions:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326887746